How can we derive the Lorentz Factor?
So I've seen a lot of derivation of it on online. Many of them are very easy to understand. But my course teacher taught this following derivation from this book which is a lot more rigourious than others. I couldn't get the expansion of that line and how the 1,0,c^2 condition worked here.
Can someone easily explain it to me? I need line by line explanation of that expansion.

Any single derivation of the Lorentz factor would do. If you can understand the simple ones, you should accept that and move on. Whatever this derivation is, it is not rigorous. At best it can be called tedious. Your picture is not enough; you need to actually take enough of a picture that we can see what those equations being referred to are.

Yeah I know any derivation would work. But as my teacher has taught this one so I have to write this specific derivation in my exams. I've added two more images. Hope it'll work now.

Where are Equation (i) and (ii)?

Please type out relevant equations and avoid posting images of textbooks where possible.

$$
\begin{align}
\tag1(x-vt)^2&=x^2-2xvt+v^2t^2\\
\tag2\left[\frac xv\left(\frac1{k^2}-1\right)+t\right]^2
&=x^2\frac1{v^2}\left(\frac1{k^2}-1\right)^2+xt\frac2v\left(\frac1{k^2}-1\right)+t^2
\end  {align}
$$
with the above two little results, we can now transform the offending equation
$$
\begin{align}
\tag3k^2(x-vt)^2+y^2+z^2&=c^2k^2\left[\frac xv\left(\frac1{k^2}-1\right)+t\right]^2\\
\tag4k^2x^2-2k^2vxt+k^2v^2t^2+y^2+z^2
&=x^2\frac{c^2k^2}{v^2}\left(\frac1{k^2}-1\right)^2+xt\frac{2c^2k^2}v\left(\frac1{k^2}-1\right)+c^2k^2t^2
\end  {align}
$$
$$\tag{viii corrected}\left[k^2-\frac{c^2k^2}{v^2}\left(\frac1{k^2}-1\right)^2\right]x^2-2k^2\left[v+\frac{c^2}v\left(\frac1{k^2}-1\right)\right]xt\\+y^2+z^2=\left[c^2k^2-v^2k^2\right]t^2
$$
We want this corrected Equation (viii) to be exactly the same as Equation (i) below. There are so many typoes in this stupid book. Your teacher should be fired for failing too many students because of bad teaching. Anyway,
$$\tag{i}x^2+y^2+z^2=c^2t^2$$
This implies that we want, simultaneously and always,
$$
\begin{align}
\tag5k^2-\frac{c^2k^2}{v^2}\left(\frac1{k^2}-1\right)^2&=1\\
\tag6v+\frac{c^2}v\left(\frac1{k^2}-1\right)&=0\\
\tag7c^2k^2-v^2k^2&=c^2
\end  {align}
$$
If you reject the negative root, i.e. reject $k<0$, then this last Equation (7) already implies that
$$\tag8k=\frac1{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
Equation (8) obviously makes Equation (6) be satisfied, and you can check that Equation (5) is also satisfied. And so everything is ok.
This book does not even use the standard notation of $\gamma$. It is cursed, and needs to be burnt. There is no rigour in this. Stupid derivation. In fact, highly inferior. I guarantee that if you write this derivation in your exams, you will fail, and you ought to fail.

Thanks a million man! I guess I needed a teacher like you.

You’re probably trying to derive it from coordinate system features, given the equations I see in your book. I honestly prefer the approach that uses the spacetime metric, so I will detail that here. If it’s not what you’re looking for, I’m sure that another good answer can be provided.
Consider that we are moving about the $x$-axis only: $\mathrm{d}y= \mathrm{d}z=0$. Then, write out the Minkowski metric:
$$\mathrm{d}s^2=c^2 \mathrm{d}\tau^2=c^2 \mathrm{d}t^2-\mathrm{d}x^2.$$
Here, $\mathrm{d}\tau$ is proper time (time experienced by moving observer in given frame) and $\mathrm{d}t$ is coordinate time (time experienced by observer stationary in given frame).
Drop the $\mathrm{d}s^2$, we don’t need it for our derivation:
$$c^2 \mathrm{d}\tau^2=c^2 \mathrm{d}t^2-\mathrm{d}x^2.$$
You should know that $v= \mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d}t$, so
$$c^2 \mathrm{d}\tau^2=c^2 \mathrm{d}t^2-v^2 \mathrm{d}t^2=(c^2-v^2) \mathrm{d}t^2.$$
Then it follows that
$$c^2\frac{\mathrm{d}\tau^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}=c^2-v^2.$$
Then,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\tau^2}{\mathrm{d}t}=1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}=1-\beta^2,$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\tau}{\mathrm{d}t}=\sqrt{1-\beta^2},$$
and then at last
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\equiv\gamma\equiv\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}$$
by definition. Note that this means that coordinate time lapse $\mathrm{d}t$ simply equals $\gamma \mathrm{d}\tau$, as one would expect: when moving fast, the same proper time the moving observer experiences equates to more coordinate time in the frame in which they are moving.
